# Django: TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, templatetags

I am getting this issue when I type `localhost:8000/admin/`.

> `TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: ':password_change' from 'admin:password_change'. The syntax of 'url' changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.

Here's part of my `settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'grappelli',
    'filebrowser',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    #'django.contrib.admindocs',
     'tinymce',
     'sorl.thumbnail',
     'south',
     'django_facebook',
     'djcelery',
     'devserver',
     'main',
)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'django_facebook.FacebookCustomUser'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_facebook.auth_backends.FacebookBackend', 
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    # Uncomment the following to make Django tests pass:
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Did I do anything wrong?

PS: This is my full traceback
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e8c1359d384df7a6b405

EDIT:

I am pasting the output of grep as per request:

```
$ ack-grep --type=python -r ':password_change' .
lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py
264:url = reverse('admin:password_change_done', current_app=self.name)

lib/python2.7/site-packages/grappelli/dashboard/dashboards.py
147:reverse('%s:password_change' % site_name)],

$ ack-grep --type=html -r ':password_change' .
lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html
36:<a href="{% url 'admin:password_change' %}">{% trans 'Change password' %}</a> /

lib/python2.7/site-packages/grappelli/templates/admin/includes_grappelli/header.html
12:{% url admin:password_change as password_change_url %}
```

Comment: can you do a folder wide search for `:password_change` and show the template which has the code ?

Comment: RIght, thanks. I just pasted the output.

Comment: I just had this problem because the template had code like `{% if thing in ['literal', 'list', 'of', 'elements'] %}`, which works in jinja but doesn't with Django templates.

Comment: it also happens when you wrote `{{ url ..` instead of `{% url ..`

Answer (score 148, accepted):

This error usually means you've forgotten a closing quote somewhere in the template you're trying to render. For example: `{% url 'my_view %}` (wrong)  instead of `{% url 'my_view' %}` (correct). In this case it's the colon that's causing the problem. Normally you'd edit the template to use the correct `{% url %}` [syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

But there's no reason why the django admin site would throw this, since it would know it's own syntax. My best guess is therefore that `grapelli` is causing your problem since it changes the admin templates. Does removing grappelli from installed apps help?

Comment: Thanks, I just did a grep in my virtualevn and it seems that `grapelli` has to do something with it. Is it fixable?

Comment: Ok, I changed `{% url admin:password_change as password_change_url %}` to `{% url 'admin:password_change' as password_change_url %}` (added the single quotes) and it seems to work. Single quotes need to be added to other places, too. The file that needs to be changed is this: `lib/python2.7/site-packages/grappelli/templates/admin/includes_grappelli/header.html`.

Comment: I would like to add that I got this error when use `{{}}` when I should have been using `{%%}`

Answer (score 12):

For me it was using {{ }} instead of {% %}:

```
href="{{ static 'bootstrap.min.css' }}"  # wrong
href="{% static 'bootstrap.min.css' %}"  # right
```

Comment: Using {{% %}} also gives this error.

Answer (score 5):

There should not be a space after `name`.

Incorrect:

```
{% url 'author' name = p.article_author.name.username %}
```

Correct:

```
{% url 'author' name=p.article_author.name.username %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Template Syntax Error: is due to many reasons one of them is {{ post.date_posted|date: "F d, Y" }} is the space between colon(:) and quote (") if u remove the space then it work like this ..... {{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the cause of the syntax error in this question, based on the error message.

Answer (score 2):

In **templates/admin/includes_grappelli/header.html**, line 12, you forgot to put `admin:password_change` between `'`.

The url Django tag syntax should always be like:

```
{% url 'your_url_name' %}
```

Answer (score 2):

for me, when I checked if condition:
This made error:

```
{%if number==10 %}
```

This solved error:

```
{% if number == 10 %}  #you may notice about space!
```

Answer (score 1):

also happens when you use jinja templates (which have different syntax for calling object methods) and you forget to set it in settings.py

Comment: <form action="{% url ('orders:remove' pizza_id=pizzacart.index(pizza)) %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button>Remove from cart</button>
        </form>   Can you find the error in this code.Pizzacart is a list containing details related to pizzas and pizza represents each of them.

Answer (score 1):

You have indented part of your code in settings.py:

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    #'django.contrib.admindocs',
     'tinymce',
     'sorl.thumbnail',
     'south',
     'django_facebook',
     'djcelery',
     'devserver',
     'main',
```

Therefore, it is giving you an error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using static files and URLs properly

```
<link href="{% static 'css/semantic.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

- Check it is properly surrounded with quotation marks or not
- Check beginning and ending brackets
- Check tag is closed properly or not

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: ':test' from 'my_app1:test'

Because I didn't use quotes for `my_app1:test` with [url tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url) as shown below. *Since [Django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/1.5/), quotes have been needed:

```
<a href="{% url my_app1:test %}">Test</a>
            {% ↑ No quotes  ↑ %}
```

So, I used quotes for `my_app1:test` with `url` tag as shown below, then the error was solved:

```
<a href="{% url 'my_app1:test' %}">Test</a>
             {% ↑   quotes   ↑ %}
```