# Grouping Conditions in Django template if statement

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to negate the result of a group of conditions separated ors in an if statement in a django template.
Heres my code

```
{% if not (owner.home_number or owner.work_number or owner.mobile_number) %}
    No contact number available
{% endif %}
```

I am currently getting this error

> TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder:
>   '(owner.home_number' from '(owner.home_number'

Comment: Have you forgotten to add some closing quotes? (ref. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428572/django-templatesyntaxerror-could-not-parse-the-remainder-password-change-f))

Comment: I dont think so... when I take out the parenthesis I dont get a syntax error.

Comment: According to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#is-not-operator), "is not True" can be appended to the if-statement i.e., `if owner.home_number or owner.work_number or owner.mobile_number is not True`.  (Note: I haven't tested this.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the [order of evaluation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#complex-expressions) is the following:

- or
- and
- not

you can omit the parenthesis:

```
{% if not owner.home_number or owner.work_number or owner.mobile_number %}
    No contact number available
{% endif %}
```

Or, just FYI, you can also reverse the check:

```
{% if owner.home_number or owner.work_number or owner.mobile_number %}
{% else %}
    No contact number available
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I ended up doing this but I was wondering why the parenthesis doesnt work in django templating...

Comment: @Crystal you cannot use parenthesis, it is not allowed [by design](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#boolean-operators). Consider accepting the answer if you think it deserves. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the order of evaluation, I guess I assumed that the precedence was what I was used to (not being the first in the list)... this makes me wonder how I would negate a single condition in the group

Comment: I guess I would just have to nest the condition if I have to negate one of the conditions

Comment: According to the link: "The precedence of the operators is `from lowest to highest`"

Comment: This answer is **NOT correct**.  See comment by @S_M.  In other words, the expression `not owner.home_number or owner.work_number or owner.mobile_number` will be interpreted as `(not owner.home_number) or owner.work_number or owner.mobile_number`, which is **not** what the OP wanted.

Comment: @typeracer thanks for the note! Please consider submitting an edit request to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`(` not a valid syntax here.

If you want to convert: `if is_admin and (requested or exempted)`

you could use something like:

```
{% if is_admin and requested or is_admin and exempted %}
```