# Could not parse the remainder: '==obj.id' from 'sobj.id==obj.id'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

i am using nested for loop in django template to print data which i get from the data base

```
            {% if objectives %}
            {% for obj in objectives %}
            {% for sobj in sobjective %}
            {% if sobj.id==obj.id %} yes {% endif %}
```

all the open tags are closed

but its raising an error
as i mentioned above

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /objectives
Could not parse the remainder: '==obj.id' from 'sobj.id==obj.id'
```

Comment: Add spaces around `==`.

Comment: Have you looked at the solutions mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428572/django-templatesyntaxerror-could-not-parse-the-remainder)? It's possible that the error is not in the code snippet you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django template language requires spaces around the `==` operator, so you should implement this as:

```
{% if sobj.id == obj.id %} yes {% endif %}
```

In Python `x==y` would be valid, but Django's template language has specific tokens and grammar.

Comment: thank you very much for your help i have another issue its about scope i am using a variable in try: tage but when i create a dictionary outside of "try" django rais an error that local variable referenced before assignment i try to change the scope by writing global but it does not fixed my error by the way . you have any idea about that?