# How to index in Django Templates

Tags: django, templates, jinja2

Im trying to index a 2D list, whenever I access `members.0`, for example, the positioning works just fine. However I need this to change with the loop so I made a variable, but, if I was to do `members.counter` this wouldn't do anything.
Is there another way of doing this or is it not possible?

```
  <tbody>
      {% for item in projects %}
      {% with counter=forloop.counter0 %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ item }}</td>
        <td>{{ members.counter }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endwith %}
      {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the square brackets `[]` if you need to [access a list or dict at a specific position](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#variables):

```html
<tbody>
  {% for item in projects %}
    {% with counter=forloop.counter0 %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ item }}</td>
        <td>{{ members[counter] }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endwith %}
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Yeah i've already did try that out but get an error saying "Could not parse the remainder: '[counter]' from 'members[counter]'". I had a quick look but no immediate fixes

Comment: For this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19431816/2123530