# Django: TemplateSyntaxError at /category/2/

Tags: django

**1. Summarize the problem**

I great custom tag. In file news_tags.py

```
from django import template

from news.models import Category

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag()
def get_categories():
    return Category.objects.all()
```

---

I called the tag in the sidebar.html file

```
{% load news_tags %}
{% get_categories %}

<div class="list-group">
    {% for item in categories %}
    <a href="{% url 'category' item.pk %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{ item.title }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

---

This my [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUi8o.png)

---

My Error:
TemplateSyntaxError at /category/2/
'news_tags' is not a registered tag library

---

**2. Describe what you’ve tried**

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428572/django-templatesyntaxerror-could-not-parse-the-remainder) question. But there was an error in an unclosed quote

I looked at [this](https://qna.habr.com/q/741559) question. I write in settings.py TEMPLATES.options.context_processors `'mainsite.news.template_tags.news_tags',`. But error `No module named 'mainsite.news'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder name must be `templatetags`.

Make sure you are not missing any of the following steps:

1. Create a folder called `templatetags` at the same level as `models.py`
   and `views.py` in your application folder
2. Your application must be in the `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`
3. The `templatetags` folder must have `__init__.py`
4. Restart the django server